curl: (60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
I just updated a web server from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04, everything seems fine except cURL which returns an error:

curl: (60) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

I checked the ssh_config and sshd_config but could not see anything wrong. Do I need to regenerate the certificates now? I don't see why they would suddenly become invalid.

Fixed! In the end I added the fingerprint for the server into my known_hosts file and it works fine.
